# Decorator Pattern, via inheritance or dependency injection?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

Right now I am studying the common design patterns and for the most part I understand the purpose of the decorator pattern. But what I don't get is, what is the purpose of wrapping an existing object in a decorator class?

Consider this scenario, since Progress is part of the observer pattern, I want to limit the amount of updates to its subscribers to prevent the UI thread from locking.

So I have decorated the class to only update once every 50 milliseconds.

```
public class ProgressThrottle<T> : Progress<T>
{
    private DateTime _time = DateTime.Now;
    public ProgressThrottle(Action<T> handler) : base(handler)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnReport(T value)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(50) < _time)
        {
            base.OnReport(value);
            _time = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

public class ProgressThrottle2<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private DateTime _time = DateTime.Now;

    private readonly IProgress<T> _wrapper;

    public ProgressThrottle2(IProgress<T> wrapper)
    {
        _wrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void Report(T value)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(50) < _time)
        {
             _wrapper.Report(value);
            _time = DateTime.Now;

        }
    }
```

Both classes accomplish the same thing, except I find the first version better because it allows me to use the base constructor for setting the delegate for progress updates. The base class already supports overriding the method, so what is the need for me wrap the object?

Are both classes example of the decorator pattern? I would much rather use the first option but I rarely see examples in that manner.

Comment: What roles in the Decorator pattern did you consider? This is part of the *research effort* for good questions, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have `n` different implementations of the `IProgress<T>` interface.

For the sake of this example, let's consider two implementations:

- `EndpointProgress<T>`, this would poll an endpoint and `Report` every time the response is different.
- `QueryProgress<T>`, this would execute a database query periodically and `Report` every time the result is different.

In order to throttle both of these implementations using your first approach, you'd have to create two implementations of your `ProgressThrottle<T>`, one inheriting from `EndpointProgress<T>`, and another one inheriting from `QueryProgress<T>`.

In order to throttle both of these implementations using the second approach you'd just have to use a wrapped instance of `EndpointProgress<T>` and `QueryProgress<T>`.

```
var throttledEndpointProgress = new ProgressThrottle2<int>(new EndpointProgress<T>());
var throttledQueryProgress = new ProgressThrottle2<int>(new QueryProgress<T>());
```

---

## Edit:

> So in a scenario were I am certain I will not extend a class more than once to add functionality, is it acceptable to not use a wrapper?

I still would use the second implementation of the decorator (I'm not even sure of the first implementation would be considered the decorator pattern) for several reasons:

- [S.**O**.L.I.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles' [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) states that:

  > Software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification.

  I you have to modify your current `Progress` implementation in order to extend it, you are violating Open/Closed.
- Having `ProgressThrottle` inherit from `Progress` means that every time `Progress`' constructor changes, `ProgressThrottle` also needs its constructor changed.
- By using wrapper decorators, you're able to compose and combine decorators. Let's consider an implementation of `IProgress<T>` that logs every `onReport` call. You could —based on configuration, environment, etc— compose these decorators in different ways to achieve different goals:

  ```
  var progress1 = new LoggingProgress<int>(
      new ProgressThrottle<int>(new Progress<int>())
  );
  var progress2 = new ProgressThrottle<int>(
      new LoggingProgress<int>(new Progress<int>())
  );
  ```

  Here, `progress1` will only log the throttled reported progress. `progress2` will log all the reported progress, but will report in a throttled manner. Depending on what your objectives are you might want one implementation or the other; or you might want both of them, one for diagnostics in staging and another one for prod, but the most important thing is that you don't have to change the implementation of your decorator in order to change this behavior.

Comment: So in a scenario were I am certain I will not extend a class more than once to add functionality, is it acceptable to not use a wrapper? Adding a wrapper  later on in the future wouldn't be complicated. Or is best practice is to use a wrapper anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't use design patterns just for the shake of using them. As Maximo explained, the decorator allows new functionalities to be added to an object statically or dynamically without affecting the behavior of objects of the same class. If you do not have such need, there is no need to use the decorator pattern. If you want a "best practice" as to why not to use it, just consider YAGNI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)